# Why is the "The other idea of momentum" more physically relevant?

Tags: momentum, intuition

So I was reading Graviation: Misner, Thorne, Wheeler and on Page 53 I came across an interesting passage:

> Multiply the mass $m$ of the momentum vector to obtain the momentum
> vector:
>
> $$ \vec p = m \vec u$$
>
> But physics gives also quite another idea to momentum. It associates a
> de Brogile wave with each particle. Moreover, this wave has the most
> direct possible physical significance. From the pattern of
> diffraction, but also the pattern in space made by surfaces  of equal
> integral phase $\phi = 7$, $\phi = 8$, $\phi = 9$. This pattern of
> surfaces, given a name "$\vec k$"  provide the simplest illustration
> of one-forms one can find.
>
> ....
>
> Take two near by spacetime points. Run an arrow $\vec v = P - P_0$
> from $P$ to $P_0$. With their aid, the precise value $\langle \vec k ,
>  \vec v \rangle = \phi(P) - \phi(P_0) $. It will pierce a certain
> number of the De Broglie wave's surfaces of integral phase, with a
> bong of imaginary bell at each piercing. The number of surfaces
> pierced is denoted by:
>
> $$ \langle \vec k , \vec v \rangle = \Phi(P) - \Phi(P_0)$$
>
> ...

While I think I get what he goes on about I don't get why he says **this way has the more direct possible physical significance** and what advantage this formulation has over the normal $m  \vec u$ ?

Comment: See [The more general uncertainty principle, beyond quantum](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MBnnXbOM5S4)